# Nested flatmap observable rxJava

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java

Say I have a blog post api that returns `List<Post>` which I'd like to translate into something else Using RxJava.  Overall I'd like to break a long string into paragraphs and then words, do something to each word, combine back into paragraphs and combine back into a blog post.  Each  Post can be broken into multiple paragraphs which then could be broken into multiple words. Logically I'd like to do the following and can't find a async manner to do it in.

- Create Observable from List
- Split each Observable into `Observable<String>` on `\n` which would give me paragraphs
- Split paragraphs into `Observable<String>` on `' '` which would segment into words
- Do some kind of transformation to each word (some words will have puncuation as part of them which is fine)
- combine all words back into paragraph putting a space between each one
- combine all paragraphs back into a Post putting a carriage return back between each one.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do multiple levels of splitting and combining on a particular term.  If I only needed to split into pages I can do something like flatmap(Observable::from).toList() but that won't seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you already have the list of posts up-front, wouldn't it make sense to use streams instead of RxJava? See http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

Comment: I'm working on android and currently am in a project that only has access to RxJava for async support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work fine, the code is pretty self-explanatory.

I make some nested calls to `Observable#from` to split posts to paragraphs and paragraphs to words. Then I use [`Observable#reduce`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#reduce(rx.functions.Func2)) to concatenate words to obtain a single paragraph, and then `reduce` again to concatenate paragraphs to a single post.

```
Observable<List<String>> blogPostsWithReversedWords(List<String> blogPosts) {
    return Observable.from(blogPosts)
            .flatMap(this::blogPostToParagraphs)
            .toList();
}

Observable<String> blogPostToParagraphs(String post) {
    return Observable.from(post.split("\n"))
            .flatMap(this::paragraphToWords)
            .reduce((prevText, nextParagraph) -> prevText + "\n" + nextParagraph);
}

Observable<String> paragraphToWords(String paragraph) {
    return Observable.from(paragraph.split(" "))
            .map(this::reverseWord)
            .reduce((prevText, nextWord) -> prevText + "\n" + nextWord);
}

String reverseWord(String word) {
    return new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you, I was using collect but reduce looks much cleaner.